# Image height doesn't want to be adjusted in css

Tags: css, height, width

I'm having problems with an image in my project, I would like it to occupy 20% of width and the height to adjust to maintain its proportion, without stretching or compressing it, but when I try to define its height whatever it is nothing happens, and when I try to take its width makes it occupy the entire area. I don't know what in my css could be causing this so I'll send it as everything is, however the problem is happening with the image2 found in the final part.

```css
.about-me-section{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.image2{
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}

.titulo2{
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
  left: 30%;
  top: 110vh;
  font-family: system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  color: #1e1e1e;
}

.description1{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 25px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 60%;
  left: 32%;
  top: 135vh
}

.description2{
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: #1e1e1e;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 58%;
  left: 32%;
  top: 143vh
}
```

```ts
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';

const AboutMeSection = () => {
  return (
    <div className="about-me-section">
        <div className="image2">
        <img src="./selfiepretoebranco.jpg" alt="Eduardo" className="image" />
        </div>

}
```

I already tried resetting the height with different values or setting the height and making the width adjust from there, but no matter what the case, the image is not being affected by the height.

Comment: You've posted a wall of CSS, but no HTML to give it any context. While I appreciate that you attempted to share code, you need to share enough code that we can reproduce the problem. Also, the code you share needs to be minimised to the smallest amount possible that still demonstrates the problem. Please, take the [tour], and read the guidance on "*[mcve]*," and "*[ask]*."

Comment: I've updated the question but making an addition, I'm creating a portfolio and this photo would be mine in the upper left corner of the screen next to other information.

Comment: You haven’t shown us an important bit, which is what the image class consists of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `img`'s parent to `width:20%;` and the `img` to `width:100%;`:

```css
.about-me-section{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.image2{
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;
}
.image{
  width:100%
}
```

```html
<div class="about-me-section">
    <div class="image2">
    <img src="https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/54e2d6444d56b10ff3d8992cc12c30771037dbf852547940752779d79e4b_640.jpg" alt="Eduardo" class="image" />
</div>
```

Comment: This was not the solution but it got me to find what is causing the error to occur, thanks a lot!